# "Гул(,) словно от безликой толпы". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул ― гул словно от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.*

Нужна ли запятая перед словно?

Comment: Без запятых; комменты с сомненьями читала.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятая не нужна, здесь оборот имеет значение уподобления; союз можно вообще убрать, структура предложения не изменится.

Только два "гула" подряд совсем не смотрятся. Предложение желательно редактировать, например так: **Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул ― словно от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.**

Определения к слову гул  [https://kartaslov.ru/каким-бывает/гул](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB)

Comment: Хорошо. Если в Вашем отредактированном предложении перед словно будет слово гул, нужна ли будет запятая перед словно?           Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул ― гул словно от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.

Comment: Действительно, вопрос о пунктуации. Уж точно не о гуле.

Comment: @shampar Да, была у меня такая уверенность, что подобный вопрос будет задан, надо было сказать что-то и про запятую, чтобы не попасть под санкции. А "гул" - это допуслуга, мне просто сервис понравился. Хорошо сейчас писателям, напрягаться лишний раз не надо.

Comment: @ абвг  Нет, запятая не нужна, здесь оборот имеет значение уподобления, союз можно вообще убрать, структура предложения не изменится. Только два "гула" подряд совсем не смотрятся.

Comment: @ абвг Если хотите оставить *гул* два раза, прелагаю вариант: "Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул, ― гул, словно исходящий от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда." (§ 175. Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное, усиливающее, дополняющее или развивающее главное предложение) дальнейшую часть того же предложения) (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

Comment: @Jasmin, Как Вы относитеь к § 175 (см.  выше)? Разве не нужна  запятая вместе с тире в исходном варианте?

Comment: 1) Смысл предложения не очень ясен: что это за гул? Так как использован союз СЛОВНО, то это не гул от толпы, а только "словно гул от толпы".  Поэтому такое предложение трудно анализировать. 2) При повторе словА  находятся не  рядом, а на расстоянии, например:  В воздухе стоял странный гул, невнятный, многоголосый, ни на минуту не прекращающийся, - гул, который может исходить от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Д. В. Дмитриева:
[**гул**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/891/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB)
*сущ., м., употр. сравн. часто*
**Гул** — это продолжительный глухой шум, который машины, военная техника, большое количество людей и т. д. издают одновременно.
Гул орудийных залпов. | Послышался гул тяжёлых машин. | Мне не удалось перекричать нестройный гул голосов.

Мне *кажется*, что во фразе *гул от безликой толпы* предлог **от** является лишним.
Я бы оформила предложение таким образом (вопрос о запятой в этом случае отпадает):
**Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул ― словно гул безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.**

*Но в далёком плеске волны

Безразличья медленный вал,

**Гул безликой тёмной толпы** —

Горе всем, кто это познал.*
Сергей Гришунов

Comment: В зале стоял приглушённый гул от разговоров, шарканья ног и стука посуды. [Григорий Трунов. Поездка в город // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]. Толпа гудит только в переносном смысле. Гул от толпы — гул, исходящий от толпы.