# «Гул толпы» или «гул от толпы»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, словосочетания

Отвечала на вопрос ["Гул(,) словно от безликой толпы". Нужна ли запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437234/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F) и привела выдержку из словаря Д. В. Дмитриева.

[**гул**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/891/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB)
*сущ., м., употр. сравн. часто*
**Гул** — это продолжительный глухой шум, который машины, военная техника, большое количество людей и т. д. издают одновременно.
Гул орудийных залпов. | Послышался гул тяжёлых машин. | Мне не удалось перекричать нестройный гул голосов.

Мне *показалось*, что предлог **от** в словосочетании **гул от толпы** "лишний":
гул безликой толпы; гул тёмной толпы.

Комментарий к моему ответу:
*В зале стоял приглушённый гул от разговоров, шарканья ног и стука посуды. [Григорий Трунов. Поездка в город // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]. Толпа гудит только в переносном смысле. Гул от толпы — гул, исходящий от толпы.*

Так нужен предлог **ОТ** или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **гул толпы**.

В Нацкопусе: гул толпы — 60 примеров, гул от толпы — 0 примеров. http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E3%F3%EB++%F2%EE%EB%EF%FB

Гул машин, гул толпы — это **звуки**, исходящие от машин, от толпы. Мы же не говорим: пение от птиц, шум от ручья.

А как же: ***Гул (от чего?) от разговоров, шарканья ног и стука посуды***. Здесь гул происходит от **смешения** отдельных звуков.

Приведенное предложение нужно исправить: ***Стоял невнятный, многоголосый гул ― словно гул  безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда.***

Comment: Именно так я в своем ответе и написала предложение. Дополнительно привела пример. Мнение авторитетного @М_Г заставило меня засомневаться.

Comment: "Толпа гудит только в переносном смысле"? А что это значит? Почитаем словарь. ГУЛ, - Длительный непрерывный и не вполне различимый шум. Гул голосов. Гул моря. Самолётный, орудийный гул. Толпа - источник такого шума. Что же здесь переносного? И почему же он не заглянул в Нацкорпус?

Answer (score 0):

*Гул от разговоров* - скорее нужен, чем нет, а *гул толпы* - не нужен. Но ведь у вас *гул словно от безликой толпы*, а это дело другое. Здесь предлог не уберешь.

Answer (score 0):

Я все-таки настаиваю, что "гул от толпы" — не ошибка. Подразумевается гул, исходящий от толпы.

Аргумент Ксении: Мы же не говорим: пение от птиц, шум от ручья.
Ответ: Мы не говорим "пение, исходящее от птиц", поэтому не говорим "пение от птиц". А вот "шум от ручья" можно употребить в соответствующем контексте (шум, исходящий от ручья). В Нацкорпусе много вхождений "шум от", самый подходящий пример:

> **Шум от реки**, впрочем, не силен; на противоположном берегу находится мельница, шум от которой значительно сильнее. [Д. Н. Анучин. Из поездки к истокам Днепра, Западной Двины и Волги (1891)]

Приведу еще примеры с "гул от".

> При 160 км/ч, когда стрелка тахометра пересекает 4-тысячную отметку, **гул от двигателя** перекрывает все остальные шумы и звук магнитолы хочется сделать погромче. [Игорь Сирин. Развлечение (2004) // «Бизнес-журнал», 2004.01.30]
>
> В воздухе стоял сплошной **гул от мухоты**; от дыха низкого вечернего солнца похаживал по сеннику, по сухому, измятому в лепешку прошлогоднему накосу слабый ветер. [Валентин Распутин. Дочь Ивана, мать Ивана (2003) // «Наш современник», 2003.11.15]
>
> И тут до меня ― не сразу, а как **гул от самолета**, немного погодя ― дошло, что ведь последняя электричка к нам из Новомыквинска пришла полтора часа назад! [Алексей Иванов. Земля -- Сортировочная (1990-1991)]
>
> Брызнули из-за поворота огни. Теплый **гул от улиц**.[Б. С. Житков. Виктор Вавич. Книга первая (1941)]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> Особенно раздражающе действует непрерывный, не смолкающий ни на минуту **гул от летающих вокруг сетки туч комаров**. [Г. Н. Боч. Экскурсия на Север (1926)]

Answer (score 0):

Существуют **два варианта определения предмета**: родительный беспредложный и родительный предложный.

Родительный беспредложный обозначает **источник активного признака:** дым костра, шум дождя, журчание ручья,  грохот трамвая. Звук интересен  сам по себе (журчание ручья).

Родительный предложный также может обозначать источник признака **по месту его происхождения:** свет (исходит) от фонаря, тень (падает) от дерева, также дым от костра, шум от реки, гул от самолета.

**Семантика здесь может совпадать, а может быть разной,** поэтому выбор зависит от ситуации (в некоторых случаях требуется некоторая интуиция, языковое чутьё). Например: *Я люблю слушать шум реки. Шум реки/от реки здесь был едва слышен.*

**Примеры**

1) **Гул какой** (характерный самолетный гул, предшествующий появлению самолета):

Прямо над нами нарастает **гул самолета**, вечернее небо стремительно бороздят сигнальные огни невидимой машины. [Варвара Синицына. (2002)]

2) **Гул от чего**:

И тут до меня ― не сразу, а как **гул от самолета**, немного погодя ― дошло, что ведь последняя электричка  пришла полтора часа назад! [Алексей Иванов. (1990-1991)]

**Гул безликой толпы** ― это характерный, узнаваемый звук, слияние тысячи голосов. Наличие определения (безликой толпы) говорит о том, что важен сам звук, а не указание на его происхождение.

Comment: По поводу конкретного предложения, Там **безликая толпа, спешащая неизвестно куда**. Наличие причастного оборота  приводит меня к выводу, что это не просто "характерный, узнаваемый звук", автор представляет себе такую спешащую  толпу, **от которой** исходит этот гул.

Comment: Толпа представляется как бы единым живым организмом, издающим характерный гул. Дается подробное описание этой толпы. Поэтому - гул толпы. Но звук, называемый гулом,  могут издавать разные предметы, тогда мы говорим гул от толпы, от самолета, от двигателя, указывая источник.  Разница: какой гул или гул от чего.

Comment: "Разница: какой гул или гул от чего". С этим я согласен. Для того, чтобы показать, каким был гул, не надо описывать , что толпа безлика, что она спешит неизвестно куда —  это не влияет на звук, не так ли? Но я понимаю фразу так: как будто где-то гудела безликая толпа, спешащая неизвестно куда, и гул **от нее** доносился до наших ушей. Автор заставляет нас представить такую толпу в движении.

Comment: Если Вы Хотите сказать, что это гул от толпы, а не от самолета, то пожалуйста. Но если хотите создать художественный образ "голоса" толпы, указывая дополнительные сведения о ней (а толпа может быть разной), то, согласитесь, это будет именно "гул/голос толпы".

Comment: Что хотел сказать автор нужно у него спросить. А я могу сказать, как я воспринимаю каждый из этих вариантов. "Гул от безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда" - мое воображение рисует такую толпу, от нее исходит гул. "Гул безликой толпы, спешащей неизвестно куда" — у меня возникает вопрос: как гудит безликая толпа, спешащая неизвестно куда, что особенного в таком гуле, какой такой специфический звук автор хотел описать? А ответа нет, остается чувство растерянности: либо я дурак, либо автор заумный.

Comment: Наверное, гул толпы может быть разным: неопределенным (как в нашем случае), одобрительным, неодобрительным, угрожающим. Вероятно, это хотел сказать автор, но если читатель его не понял, значит коммуникативное общение не состоялось.